# VB script to store a date string in a filename and compare with current date

Tags: vbscript

I have a filename with a datestamp within it. I would like to compare the date in the file name with the current date, and perform an action (move the file to a 'backup' folder) if it is older.

Here are some examples of file formats:

```
TEST_COPT_PART_TAX_09Feb2015_080529
TEST_COPT_PART_YTD_09Feb2015_080529
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should use date variables and functions (CDate, DateSerial, DateDiff, ...) when working with dates. But in this special case, a stringy approach may work:

(1) Pre-build a string for the current date

```
>> dToday = Date()
>> sToday = Right("0" & Day(dToday), 2) & MonthName(Month(dToday), True) & Year(dToday)
>> WScript.Echo sToday
>>
12Feb2015
```

(2) Use InStr() or = on Mid() to determine whether **not** to move the file.

If that fails - because of the MonthNames or a change of the definition of "older" in the specs - you need to cut and re-format the date part of the file name suitable for CDate():

```
>> WScript.Echo CDate("09Feb2015")
>>
Error Number:       13
Error Description:  Type mismatch
>> WScript.Echo CDate("09 Feb 2015")
>>
09.02.2015  <-- German Locale
```

or DateSerial():

```
>> s = Right("TEST_COPT_PART_TAX_09Feb2015_080529", 16)
>> d = DateSerial(CInt(Mid(s, 6, 4)), 2, CInt(Mid(s, 1, 2)))
>> WScript.Echo d
>>
09.02.2015  <-- German Locale
```

(mapping the month names to numbers suitable for DateSerial() is left as an exercise)

Comment: I used the below line to remove the extension of files in the source folder so as to pick up any type of extension with the above file name           
fname = Left(ObjFile.Name, (InStrRev(objFile.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))

Below code to filter the "TEST_COPT_PART_TAX_" so as to get alone the date part
DateStampFilter = Right(fname, 18)
But I cant get the date trimmed out from the file name.
After that I need to format the date as per the sys time for comparison.
I'm doing something wrong with the above codes. show some light.

Your help is much appreciated..!!

Comment: @Carthiksharma - no lights to show, as cutting parts from the file name has nothing to do with the two methods I showd you to determine whether a given name 'belongs' to today.